# Character rotation and move to mouse click point with speed

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, geometry

I need simulate forward rotation of the character in my 2D game project.

I have tried to create my movement script but it doesn't works perfect. The reason is my 2D actor is spaceship and it can't do rotation around his axis but i need just forward rotation for it.

[image]

Here is a two parts of this movement.

- Actor must go forward and rotate to turn back (the radius must be optimal or pre-defined).
- Actor must go straight by line using mouse click location.

So. I use Unity engine. Need some explanations to release it.

Thank you!

**UPD:** My current source code:

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

 public float speed = 1.5f;
 public float rotationSpeed = 90f;
 private Vector3 pos;
 private Quaternion qTo;

 void Start () {
  pos = transform.position;
  qTo = transform.rotation;
 }

 void Update () {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
   pos = Input.mousePosition;
   pos.z = transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
   pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
  }

  var dir = pos - transform.position;

  if (dir != Vector3.zero) {
   qTo = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, pos - transform.position);
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards (transform.rotation, qTo, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
  }

  transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
 }    

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your ship not an ambiturner?  Why wouldn't it not turn clockwise instead of anticlockwise?  In any case, writing games needs a certain understanding of mathematics... what part of this are you getting stuck with?  If you can add two vectors this should be trivial.

Comment: **"provide me your code in C# or Javascript"** Really? You have over 400 reputation and still don't know how this site work... You did not even provide a code. Ok, let's say you put an effort but your code does not work then we can help you.

Comment: @Programmer sorry i incorrectly said. Corrected.

Comment: @J... no. So, i guess it must be optimal. But there are other situation when the ship in other direction

Comment: i've attached my current source. What's wrong? Ship is rotating and moving so it looks so strange instead of do rotation with some radius and then move.

Comment: I see a script now. The spaceship is going to the right(x+ axis)? I am trying to understand what you are doing. Is there any short gif or maybe youtube video with similar control of what you are doing?

Comment: @Programmer  thank you for answer. What video you interested to see expected movement or existing?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are doing. So I am asking there is any game that has similar function....If so you can post  a link to that maybe it will help understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Yeah. The similar game is space rangers but in my case control that movement not just clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dir = pos - transform.position;
qTo = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, pos - transform.position);

if (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, qTo) >= rotPrecision) //just set your own precision
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, qTo, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,pos) > movePrecision) // 0.1f
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Is not working properly. When precision is small there are no changes. When precision=30 (for example) i have just reduced movement.

Comment: can you explain beginning of that red arrow? (I saw it just now)

Comment: I guess in that case it should rotate around right corner. I'm not sure...

Comment: I changed answer. Look at it now.